# Install fasttext on Windows 10 with anaconda

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, fasttext

I am trying to install fasttext in anaconda with Windows 10 using the command: pip install fasttext as explained here: https://pypi.org/project/fasttext/

The error messages are:

```
ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1900
```

and

```
Command "c:\users\nicol\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\nicol\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pd0xqmlg\\fasttext\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4qt38yfk\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pd0xqmlg\fasttext\
```

Can you tell me how I can fix this problem?

The only requirement listed is Cython, which I have:

```
(C:\Users\nicol\Anaconda3) C:\Users\nicol>pip install Cython
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in c:\users\nicol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.25.2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
pip install fasttext_win
```

If this works, credits to cmoscardi for his response in GitHub.
https://github.com/salestock/fastText.py/issues/167#issuecomment-404258960

Comment: You have to install first Cython, then run the command given by @Shree, it works for me