# How to install fastText library in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I'd like to install the fastText library for text classification. Could anyone suggest how to install it?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201570/install-fasttext-on-windows-10-with-anaconda

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo pip install fastText
```

Run in a bash shell (linux) or 
select it with pip in visual studio (windows) or
get it directly at GitHub
...
There are many possible ways. But I'd recommend pip, because it is convenient to manage different libraries.
For this to work you have to have cython installed.

Comment: If you are using Windows just type it without `sudo`

Comment: unless you use the subsystems

Comment: Thanks, that really help me to resolve my issues. Cheers!

Comment: A popular dependency manager for python is `poetry`. Sadly it has a problem with the way fasttext is packaged. See: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/6113